Implement event pattern aws cdk Typescript
I have this event pattern that I want to set using aws cdk in Typescript, but I am getting an error that source must be an array of strings. I tested just using source: ["aws.partner/stripe.com"] but the events are not processed. Seems like the prefix is required.
How can I get the prefix to be included in the source?
export class EventBridgeRuleStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(
        scope: Construct,
        id: string,
        eventBus: cdk.aws_events.IEventBus,
        lambda: cdk.aws_lambda.IFunction,
        props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        
        // Create an EventBridge rule
        const rule = new cdk.aws_events.Rule(this, "EventRule", {
            eventBus: eventBus,
            ruleName: "stripe-event",
            eventPattern: {
                source: [{
                    prefix: "aws.partner/stripe.com"
                }]
            }
        });


        // Add the Lambda function as a target
        rule.addTarget(new cdk.aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction(lambda));

    }
}


that was just a typing mistake. Removed it, still the same issue

I came upon this thread, https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6184
Based on that I was able to get it to work like this:
export class EventBridgeRuleStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(
        scope: Construct,
        id: string,
        eventBus: cdk.aws_events.IEventBus,
        lambda: cdk.aws_lambda.IFunction,
        props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        
        // Create an EventBridge rule
        const rule = new cdk.aws_events.Rule(this, "EventRule", {
            eventBus: eventBus,
            ruleName: "stripe-event",
            eventPattern: {
                source: cdk.aws_events.Match.prefix("aws.partner/stripe.com")
            }
        });

        rule.addEventPattern({source: []})

        // Add the Lambda function as a target
        rule.addTarget(new cdk.aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction(lambda));

    }
}

